# filling the gaps between list of angles (numbers)

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization, normalization, data-preprocessing

i'll explain for simple example then go into the deep
if i have a list of number consist of

> t_original = [180,174,168,166,162,94,70,80,128,131,160,180]

if we graph this so it goes down from 180 to 70 then it ups to 180 again

[image]
but if we suddenly change the fourth value (166) by 450 then the list will be

> t = [180,174,168,700,162,94,70,80,128,131,160,180]

which dose not make sense in the graph
[image]

i wanna treat the fourth value (700) as a wrong value
i want to replace it with a relative value even if not as the original value but **relative to the previous two elements (168,174)**
i wanna do the same for the whole list if another wrong value appeared again

we can call that [Filling gaps between list of numbers]

so i'm tryig to do the same idea but for bigger example
[image]

the method i have tried

[image]

and i'll share my code with output , filtered means applied filling gap function

my code

```
def preprocFN(*U):
prePlst=[] # after preprocessing list
#preprocessing Fc =| 2*LF1 prev by 1 - LF2 prev by 2 |
c0 = -2     #(previous) by 2
c1 =-1      #(previous)
c2 =0       #(current)
c3 = 1      #(next)
preP = U[0] # original list
if c2 == 0:
    prePlst.append(preP[0])
    prePlst.append(preP[1])
    c1+=2
    c2+=2
    c0+=2
oldlen = len(preP)
while oldlen > c2:
    Equ = abs(2*preP[c1] - preP[c0]) #fn of preprocessing #removed abs()
    formatted_float = "{:.2f}".format(Equ) #with .2 number only
    equu = float(formatted_float)          #from string float to float
    prePlst.insert(c2,equu)      # insert the preprocessed value to the List
    c1+=1
    c2+=1
    c0+=1

return prePlst
```

with my input : https://textuploader.com/t1py9

the output will be : https://textuploader.com/t1pyk

and when printing the values higher than 180 (wrong values)

```
result_list = [item for item in list if item > 180]
```

which dosen't make sense that any joint of human can pass the angle of 180

the output was [183.6, 213.85, 221.62, 192.05, 203.39, 197.22, 188.45, 182.48, 180.41, 200.09, 200.67, 198.14, 199.44, 198.45, 200.55, 193.25, 204.19, 204.35, 200.59, 211.4, 180.51, 183.4, 217.91, 218.94, 213.79, 205.62, 221.35, 182.39, 180.62, 183.06, 180.78, 231.09, 227.33, 224.49, 237.02, 212.53, 207.0, 212.92, 182.28, 254.02, 232.49, 224.78, 193.92, 216.0, 184.82, 214.68, 182.04, 181.07, 234.68, 233.63, 182.84, 193.94, 226.8, 223.69, 222.77, 180.67, 184.72, 180.39, 183.99, 186.44, 233.35, 228.02, 195.31, 183.97, 185.26, 182.13, 207.09, 213.21, 238.41, 229.38, 181.57, 211.19, 180.05, 181.47, 199.69, 213.59, 191.99, 194.65, 190.75, 199.93, 221.43, 181.51, 181.42, 180.22]

so the filling gaps fn from proposed method dosen't do it's job
any suggestion for applying the same concept with a different way ?

**Extra Info may help**

the filtered graph consists of filling gap function and then applying normalize function
i don't think the problem is from the normalizing function since the output from the filling gaps function isn't correct in my opinion maybe i'm wrong but anyway i provide the normalize steps so you get how the final filtered graph has been made

fn :

[image]

My Code :

```
def outLiersFN(*U):
outliers=[] # after preprocessing list
#preprocessing Fc =| 2*LF1 prev by 1 - LF2 prev by 2 |
c0 = -2     #(previous) by 2 #from original
c1 =-1      #(previous)      #from original
c2 =0       #(current)       #from original
c3 = 1      #(next)          #from original
preP = U[0] # original list
if c2 == 0:
    outliers.append(preP[0])
    c1+=1
    c2+=1
    c0+=1
    c3+=1
oldlen = len(preP)
M_RangeOfMotion = 90
while oldlen > c2 :
    if c3 == oldlen:
        outliers.insert(c2, preP[c2]) #preP[c2] >> last element in old list
        break
    if (preP[c2] > M_RangeOfMotion and preP[c2] < (preP[c1] + preP[c3])/2) or (preP[c2] < M_RangeOfMotion and preP[c2] > (preP[c1] + preP[c3])/2): #Check Paper 3.3.1
        Equ = (preP[c1] + preP[c3])/2 #fn of preprocessing # From third index # ==== inserting current frame
        formatted_float = "{:.2f}".format(Equ) #with .2 number only
        equu = float(formatted_float)          #from string float to float
        outliers.insert(c2,equu)      # insert the preprocessed value to the List
        c1+=1
        c2+=1
        c0+=1
        c3+=1
    else :
        Equ = preP[c2] # fn of preprocessing #put same element (do nothing)
        formatted_float = "{:.2f}".format(Equ)  # with .2 number only
        equu = float(formatted_float)  # from string float to float
        outliers.insert(c2, equu)  # insert the preprocessed value to the List
        c1 += 1
        c2 += 1
        c0 += 1
        c3 += 1
return outliers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following algorithm:

- data point `t[i]` is considered an outlier if it deviates from the average of `t[i-2], t[i-1], t[i], t[i+1], t[i+2]` by more than the standard deviation of these 5 elements.
- outliers are replaced by the average of the two elements around them.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statistics import mean, stdev

t = [180,174,168,700,162,94,70,80,128,131,160,180]

def smooth(t):
    new_t = []
    for i, x in enumerate(t):
        neighbourhood = t[max(i-2,0): i+3]
        m = mean(neighbourhood)
        s = stdev(neighbourhood, xbar=m)
        if abs(x - m) > s:
            x = ( t[i - 1 + (i==0)*2] + t[i + 1 - (i+1==len(t))*2] ) / 2
        new_t.append(x)
    return new_t

new_t = smooth(t)

plt.plot(t)
plt.plot(new_t)
plt.show()
```

[image: smoothing outliers]

Comment: kinda helped me in some situations but can you kindly check list : https://textuploader.com/t1pb4
it's after applying your algorithm , it worked and fixed many outliers except some,  can you check this graph out https://ibb.co/txVrLKs
there's a list like [66.02, 66.37, 66.98, 66.325, 65.67, 66.09, 65.515, 64.94, 64.42, 64.66, 64.655, 64.65, 64.4, 64.11, 64.12, 64.12] between angles of (177 and 174)  why  the algorithm couldn't get rid of them ? or normalize them ? @Stef

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about when you say "angles"

Comment: i meant numbers when you check the graph i pointed to low curve "wrong numbers" and it's a list between high numbers between [177,174] can we fill this gap using other trick ?